# String to 2d Array

Tags: arrays, string, 2d, converters

I want to convert a String into a 2D Array.
But my Problem is that the String should be dynamic.
The Result should be dynamic too. I've tried using queues but i cant come up with a solution.

sentence = "This is an example."
2DArray[][] = convertInto2dArray(sentence)

The 2D Array should look like this.
[[T][h][i][s],[i][s],[a][n],[e][x][a][m][p][l][e],[.]]

Comment: You want array format like that [[["T"], ["h"], ["i"], ["s"]], [["i"], ["s"]], [["d"], ["y"], ["n"], ["a"], ["m"], ["i"], ["c"]], [["t"], ["e"], ["x"], ["t"]]]

Answer (score 0):

In java multi-dimentional array is nothing but array of array, so with two diamentional array `[[T][h][i][s],[i][s],[a][n],[e][x][a][m][p][l][e],[.]]` is not possible. You should have 3 diamentional array.

Check Out: https://www.baeldung.com/java-jagged-arrays

Hope this will serve your purpose:

```
static char[][][] convert(String text) {
    String[] strSplit = text.split(" ");
    char[][][] out = new char[strSplit.length][][];

    for (int i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++) {
        char[] word = strSplit[i].toCharArray();
        char[][] inner = new char[word.length][];
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            inner[j] = new char[] { word[j] };
        }
        out[i] = inner;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Out Put:

```
[[[T], [h], [i], [s]], [[i], [s]], [[a], [n]], [[e], [x], [a], [m], [p], [l], [e], [.]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out kinda like this:

```
def stringToArray(newstring):
    words = wordsandpoints(newstring)

char newarray[wordsandpoints][]
    i=0
    row = 0
    for(;row < words;):
        for(int column=0;column < newstring.length(); column++, i++):
            if(newstring[i] =! " " or newstring[i] != ".")
            newarray[row][column] = newstring[i]
            elif(newstring[i] == ".")
            row++
            newarray[row][column] = newstring[i]
            row++
            else
            row++


    return newarray

def wordsandpoints(b):
    i = 0
    for x in b:
        if(x == " ")
            i++
        elif(x == ".")
            i = i + 2

    return i
```